# Windows Bat File to accept a parameter

Tags: windows-7

I require a little help, I am new to creating Windows Bat files, I've done programming before, but this is new for me.

What I require is a .bat file to move the first xx Files based on the parameter I input in the current directory to a different directory, again I'm new to writing windows bat files I don't know the syntax, any help would appreciated

Comment: [This](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) is a good reference, with several example scripts.

Comment: [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/237234/copy-first-10-files-from-a-folder-and-subfolders) seems similar.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters for batch files are referred to in the script as `%1`, `%2` and so on. So the first argument you pass to the script you can access with `%1`.

e.g. `C:\>test.bat Hello`  where the batch script is just:

`@echo %1
pause`

Will output "Hello"

With the rest of the script you'd need to be more specific on what you mean by first "xx" files. Sorted by date or name or some other attribute?

Comment: Ok, say I wanted to move a set of 250 files to another directory, sort them by name

Comment: @JoshAdams - This site is not a free script writing service. You have enough information to work out what you need to do. If you run into problems with specific commands, then you can ask about them, but don't expect us to do all the work for you.

Comment: @JoshAdams AFH is right about not having the community here do all the work for you. But there are plenty example scripts out there to get you started. Found this [tutorial post](https://ephams.com/2015/05/batch-script-set-number-files-copy-move/) which pretty much does what you want and explains how it works in a few minutes of searching. All you have to do is set the limit to your variable and specify your directories and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @echo off

set Source=C:\Users\Josh\documents
set Target=C:\Users\Josh\test

set MaxLimit=250

for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%G in ('dir /A-D /B "%Source%\*.*" ^| find /v /n ""') do (
move "%Source%\%%~nxH" "%Target%"
if %%G==%MaxLimit% exit /b 0
)
```

After enough research I got this to do what I want to do.